# ListView model function

Tags: qt, listview, model, qml, qtquick2

I am just getting started in Qt, and trying to make function which operates `ListView` model's elements.

I have custom made button in "myButton.qml" which has states like "normal", "pressed", "selected", etc.

`ListView` is in "main.qml". Structure is like this:

```
ListView{
    //...

    model: nameModel

    delegate: myButton {
        //...
    }

}
```

So here is my goal: this list of buttons should act like group of radiobuttons - only one can have selected state and selected state is when you press button. I think that I should have click handler and a function that calls on button click. Function should check the list of buttons and if one button was selected before function just changes its state to "Normal".

So I have no idea of how to write this func and where should I place it. I read Qt docs but still no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible easy way to solve this problem is by exploiting [`ExclusiveGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-exclusivegroup.html). As discussed in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-exclusivegroup.html#adding-support-to-exclusivegroup), support to this type can be added to *any* type:

> It is possible to add support for ExclusiveGroup for **an object or control**. It should have a **checked** property, and either a **checkedChanged**, **toggled()**, or **toggled(bool)** signal. It also needs to be **bound with ExclusiveGroup::bindCheckable()** when its ExclusiveGroup typed property is set.

You can define an `ExclusiveGroup` at the `ListView` level and implement the required logic in the `ListView` delegate. By binding the delegate `ExclusiveGroup` property to the `ExclusiveGroup` of the `ListView` you should achieve what you want, without the need of a function that crawls the model.

Final toy example to demonstrate the usage:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4


Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 500

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 10
        spacing: 20
        ExclusiveGroup { id: ex }   // the group for all the delegate

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: delegate
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: 30
            color: checked ? "yellow" : "steelblue"

            // code to have exclusive behaviour
            property bool checked: false
            property ExclusiveGroup exclusiveGroup: ex

            onExclusiveGroupChanged: {
                if (exclusiveGroup)
                    exclusiveGroup.bindCheckable(delegate)
            }

            // mouse area to trigger the property change
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: checked = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a nice example! Seems so easy to understand.

Comment: I'm glad it is helpful. Happy coding! :)